# What are the differences between the 4 difficulty levels?

Tags: the-darkness-2

When you start a new game, you can select these four difficulty levels:

- Thug
- Mobster
- Hitman (default)
- Don

What varies in the game between them? Are enemies tougher in the `Don` setting? Do I make less damage? Do I have other limitations?

Comment: Unless someone manages to dig into the game's script, this may never have an answer. For example, I have no idea whether your weapons are less effective with increasing difficulty, or if the enemies can simply take more punishment.

Answer (score -3):

Thug     = easy
Mobster  = normal
Hitman   = hard
Don      = very hard

Completing the game on the first 3 settings is pretty simple but Don is crazy, in both the demo and full game you start off in the restaurant and I personally cannot get past even that stage on Don difficulty. Like I said, crazy!

Comment: What makes Don difficulty very hard?  I think that's kind of what the question is asking.